# How to add font to web application .css file

Tags: css, web-applications, fonts, font-face

I would like to add a font to my web application using .css. I know that there is `@font-face` property in css but the problem is that when you define it you need to define the source (src) which is quiet obvious. My problem is that I want to actually add a font which is in my computer. I want to add it to my web application so that when I deploy this web application to internet it will be shown properly.

So my question is that how I can add that specific (which is in my computer) font to my web application? What would be the url for it?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontfacename';
  src: url('?') format ('?');
}
```

Comment: Refer this website. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Amadeus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supporting multiple browsers and operating systems requires several different font formats. A service such as [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) can generate the files as well as CSS for you, provided that the font data you plan to use is free of restrictions (many fonts "in your computer" are not and require licensing, which many commercial font vendors also provide).

The CSS code looks like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontName';
    src: url('FileName.eot');
    src: url('FileName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('FileName.woff') format('woff'),
         url('FileName.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('FileName.svg#FontName') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: FYI: Once you've added it as a font-face, to use it, reference the font-family: 'FontName'; attribute. body{ font-family: 'FontName', arial, sans-serif; }

Comment: I know how to use it. But why I would need to generate that file in FontSquirrel?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) to see if there is a font that is comparable to the font on your computer. This maybe a good solution if you don't want to convert and add your own fonts.

There's also services like [Typekit](https://typekit.com/) that serves up fonts for you like Google for a monthly fee.

Google Fonts lets you download the fonts to your computer so you could use it in your apps and for layout compositions in applications like Photoshop. There's also some free fonts at [LostType Co-Op](http://losttype.com/), but make sure to check the license for the font to make sure it can be used freely on the internet.

Comment: I was planning to use Segoe UI Light font but I'm not sure do I even have permission to use it, since its under Microsoft license. But that Google Fonts is good solution for this.

Comment: @AmirAl I found this discussion on one of Stack Exchange's networks - [Segoe UI](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/segoe-ui-font-licensing) Might help answer your questions about permission to use the font on the web.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will look that specific page more in details, but as far as I browse it quickly I notice that Sergoe UI Light might be usable, but I'm not yet 100% sure.